# Get data from child component to parent component in nebular ui nbwindow

Tags: angular, nebular

I have two components, one is parent and the other is child component (which doesn't have a selector). I'm using Nebular ui to create a window (using *nbWindowService.open(ChildComponent)*. There's a form in the child component and I need to get that data back into the parent component for processing.

In angular material dialogs I'd do something like **this.dialogref.close(data)**. Nebular ui doesn't have this kind of flexibility. How do I send data back to the parent component? Bearing in mind that the child component is not a direct child of the parent component and that it does not have a selector.

Answer (score 0):

for dialogs `dialogService.open` returns `onClose` observable where you can subscribe

i think for window some basic stream service is preferred

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class WindowResultService {
      private stream = new BehaviorSubject<IWindowResult>(undefined);
      public get(): Observable<IWindowResult> {
        return this.stream;
      }
      public next(data: IWindowResult) {
        this.stream.next(data);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, yeah. Thanks... I may have mixed things up... This works for dialogs... I meant the window using **nbwindow** service... Any idea how to to do the same? Nbwindow doesn't allow passing data via the close property...